# Rename Default Category (Uncategorized) Via a Function

Tags: categories, functions

I'm looking for a function to rename the default 'Uncategorized' category. The reason I need this is because I'm running a WordPress multi-site largely used by users with little technical knowledge and only allows the one, default category for their blog.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with multi-site but will changing it under settings work? `Settings -> Writing -> Default Post Category` ? I suppose another option would be to physically rename the category by editing it under Categories.

Comment: Not for this purpose it will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `wp_update_term` should do the trick:

```
wp_update_term(1, 'category', array(
  'name' => 'A Real Category Name',
  'slug' => 'real-category-name'
));
```